# How to group by month, day, morning, afternoon and sum the records with R?

Tags: r, group-by, statistics, time-series

I have a vector of dates like this:

```
 1 2014-03-10 22:54:24
 2 2014-03-10 22:53:16
 3 2014-03-10 22:53:01
 4 2014-03-10 22:52:38
 5 2014-03-10 22:52:00
 6 2014-03-01 01:13:08
 7 2014-03-01 01:11:30
 8 2014-03-01 01:07:41
 9 2014-03-01 01:05:28
10 2014-03-01 00:58:40
11 2014-03-27 18:11:57
```

How can I group by month, day, morning, afternoon or week? For instance:

```
month     sum      
2014-3     11
```

==============

```
week      sum       
2014-3-1   5  
2014-3-9   5
```

==============

```
2014-3-1 
morning   sum 
2014-3-1  5
```

Comment: Possibly by programming. What have you tried that has not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data frame like this where `time` is in POSIXct format:

```
df
                   time
1   2014-03-10 22:54:24
2   2014-03-10 22:53:16
3   2014-03-10 22:53:01
4   2014-03-10 22:52:38
5   2014-03-10 22:52:00
6   2014-03-01 01:13:08
7   2014-03-01 01:11:30
8   2014-03-01 01:07:41
9   2014-03-01 01:05:28
10  2014-03-01 00:58:40
11  2014-03-27 18:11:57
```

You can get month, week and am/pm as follows:

```
df$month <- format(df$time, '%Y-%m')
df$week <- format(df$time, '%Y-%U')
df$ampm <- ifelse(as.numeric(format(df$time, '%H')) > 12, 'pm', 'am')
df
                  time   month    week ampm
1  2014-03-10 22:54:24 2014-03 2014-10   pm
2  2014-03-10 22:53:16 2014-03 2014-10   pm
3  2014-03-10 22:53:01 2014-03 2014-10   pm
4  2014-03-10 22:52:38 2014-03 2014-10   pm
5  2014-03-10 22:52:00 2014-03 2014-10   pm
6  2014-03-01 01:13:08 2014-03 2014-08   am
7  2014-03-01 01:11:30 2014-03 2014-08   am
8  2014-03-01 01:07:41 2014-03 2014-08   am
9  2014-03-01 01:05:28 2014-03 2014-08   am
10 2014-03-01 00:58:40 2014-03 2014-08   am
11 2014-03-27 18:11:57 2014-03 2014-12   pm
```

Then, you can get your summaries using library `dplyr` like this:

```
library(dplyr)

count(df, month)
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

    month     n
    (chr) (int)
1 2014-03    11

count(df, week)
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

     week     n
    (chr) (int)
1 2014-08     5
2 2014-10     5
3 2014-12     1

count(df, ampm)
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

   ampm     n
  (chr) (int)
1    am     5
2    pm     6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the package `data.table` and get known of the class `POSIXlt`.

```
#x is assumed to be you're vector of time objects (POSIXct POSIXlt).
# The following lines are just for getting known to POSIXlt. You do not need to run these.
Secs <- as.POSIXlt(x)[[1]]
Mins <- as.POSIXlt(x)[[2]]
# ...
Month <- as.POSIXlt(x)[[5]] + 1 # months do start with 0 instead of 1
Year  <- as.POSIXlt(x)[[6]] - 100 #for 2016 the result would be 116 ...
DayOfYear <- as.POSIXlt(x)[[9]] + 1 #starts with 0
```

You can calculate more complicated values similarly. Use `data.table` now.

```
require(data.table)
X <- as.data.table(x) # creates a data.table object
setnames(X, "Time")   # names the 1 column 'Time'
X[ , month := as.POSIXlt(Time)[[5]] + 1] #adds a column month
X[ , doy:= as.POSIXlt(Time)[[8]] + 1] #adds a column day of year
#....
```

Now you can group your data.table with:

```
X[ , .N, by = doy]
X[ , .N, by = month]
# ...
```

`.N` returns the number of items in each group. You could also combine the grouping:

```
X[ , .N, by = list(doy, month)]
```

There are many nice tutorials using `data.table`s and the grouping and evaluation is similar to sql syntax (which can also be found in tutorials). 
A good link to start is the FAQ of the developer:
http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf

EDIT:

Of course you could also make more complicated columns for afternoon and morning like this:

```
X[ , afternoon:= ifelse(as.POSIXlt(x)[[3]] > 12, TRUE, FALSE)]
```

Comment: If you already at it, `data.table` already has these functions... see `?year`, `?month`, `?yday`, etc. You can also convert `x` directly to a `data.table` using `setDT` without creating a new copy. And as for resources, [this is the better/most recent one](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)